# Count the cells with same color in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying count the number of cells with the same background color and put the result in other cell with a script in google apps script, but I can't do it. I have the next script but not work and I don't know which is the problem:

```
function countbackgrounds() {
 var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var range_input = book.getRange("B3:B4");
 var range_output = book.getRange("B6");
 var cell_colors = range_input.getBackgroundColors()[0];
 var color = "#58FA58";
 var count = 0;

 for( var i in cell_colors )
  if( cell_colors[i] == color ){
    range_output.setValue(++count);
  }
  else {
    return count; 
  }
 }
```

Comment: Duplicate of: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/23881 ; their top answer is also more useful

Answer (score 23):

Easy solution if you don't want to code manually using [Google Sheets Power Tools](https://www.ablebits.com/google-sheets-add-ons/power-tools/index.php):

**Note: while the tool was free when this answer was written, it is now $43.20 per year or $89.95 for a lifetime license!**

1. Install Power Tools through the Add-ons panel (Add-ons -> Get add-ons)
2. From the Power Tools sidebar click on the Σ button and within that menu click on the "Sum by Color" menu item
3. Select the "Pattern cell" with the color markup you want to search for
4. Select the "Source range" for the cells you want to count
5. Use function should be set to "COUNTA"
6. Press "Insert function" and you're done :)

Comment: Works perfect... Thanks! :)

Comment: I am having "Please select a range with data and try again" while all the ranges are put, how to resolve?

Comment: be aware, the tool costs around 90 bucks

Comment: @tim99 wow... quite expensive. It was still free when I wrote the answer :(

Answer (score 11):

```
function countbackgrounds() {
 var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = book.getActiveSheet();
 var range_input = sheet.getRange("B3:B4");
 var range_output = sheet.getRange("B6");
 var cell_colors = range_input.getBackgroundColors();
 var color = "#58FA58";
 var count = 0;

 for(var r = 0; r < cell_colors.length; r++) {
   for(var c = 0; c < cell_colors[0].length; c++) {
     if(cell_colors[r][c] == color) {
       count = count + 1;
     }
   }
 }
    range_output.setValue(count);
 }
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use this working script:

```
/**
* @param {range} countRange Range to be evaluated
* @param {range} colorRef Cell with background color to be searched for in countRange
* @return {number}
* @customfunction
*/

function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();

  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();

  var count = 0;

  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        count=count+1;
  return count;
};
```

Then call this function in your google sheets:

```
=countColoredCells(D5:D123,Z11)
```

Comment: The above function has several issues: The regex breaks with a space in the arguments, the parameters of the function are never used, the "values" variable is never used.

Answer (score 1):

here is a working version :

```
function countbackgrounds() {
 var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var range_input = book.getRange("B3:B4");
 var range_output = book.getRange("B6");
 var cell_colors = range_input.getBackgroundColors();
 var color = "#58FA58";
 var count = 0;

 for( var i in cell_colors ){
 Logger.log(cell_colors[i][0])
  if( cell_colors[i][0] == color ){ ++count }
  }
range_output.setValue(count);
 }
```

Comment: Michael's version is more universal in that it iterates in every row and columns (if ever you have multiple columns...) I considered your example as your real use case.

Comment: Ok, which is the Michael's version? Because I have various columns to count. Thx for the answer.

Comment: Michael 's version is the one posted by Michael

Answer (score 1):

The previous functions didn't work for me, so I've made another function that use the same logic of one of the answers above: parse the formula in the cell to find the referenced range of cells to examine and than look for the coloured cells.
You can find a detailed description here: [Google Script count coloured with reference](https://www.barattalo.it/coding/count-coloured-cells-on-google-sheets/), but the code is below:

```
function countColoured(reference) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var args = formula.match(/=\w+\((.*)\)/i)[1].split('!');
  try {
    if (args.length == 1) {
      var range = sheet.getRange(args[0]);
    }
    else {
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName(args[0].replace(/'/g, ''));
      range = sheet.getRange(args[1]);
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    throw new Error(args.join('!') + ' is not a valid range');
  }
  var c = 0;
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
      c = c + ( range.getCell(i,j).getBackground() == "#ffffff" ? 0 : 1 );
    }
  }
  return c > 0 ? c : "" ;
}
```