# Count all colored cells in column (all different colors)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a column, I have many cells with different background color and I want to count them all. Cells don't have any value (empty, just background color).

Comment: you will need a script for that

Comment: Add some code as to what you attempted?

Comment: See the thread [Count the cells with same color in google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365436/count-the-cells-with-same-color-in-google-spreadsheet) with script and non-script options

Comment: Range class has a method [getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds) which will help you.